# How soon until we can change the favicon?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Right now the favicon says "MTV", which isn't likely to cause confusion, but it still a slight annoyance to the perfectionist within me.

Does the site need to graduate from beta before a custom favicon can be used, or do we just need someone to supply a good new icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site needs to graduate from beta before a custom theme will be used - until that time the M&TV icon will probably remain.

Comment: Regarding that, [some places it uses `MTV`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/movies/img/favicon.ico?v=ff27ba7bac7b) and [other places it uses `M&TV`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/movies/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=b11fb6054bed). Can that be fixed while the site is still in beta?

Comment: Yet there are other beta-sites which have some custom icon (yet still inside the usual blue beta "speech bubble"), like [anime.se] or [aviation.se]. But maybe just because their abbreviations would have collided with other existing beta sites.

Comment: @IQAndreas - I was not aware of that - I only notice the M&TV one. I'm sure it can be fixed, but SE move fairly slowly on these things.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - you are indeed correct, I've never noticed those ones before.

Comment: Any in either case, I've been told no significant site changes before graduation.

Comment: *"The site needs to graduate from beta before a custom theme will be used"* - Well, then the question is of course *How soon until we graduate?* ;-)